# Nodejs - best way to know a service status [linux]

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, service, child-process

Do someone know the best way (or just a good one) to know a service status from a linux (centos, here) system ?
When i run this piece of code:

```
{ ... }
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process'),
  ts3 = spawnSync('service teamspeak status | grep active'),
  { ... },
```

This throw me a ENOENT error. I got the same error from my windows system when I tried a simple dir command, I had to write a stupid cmd file named "dir.cmd" with the content "dir" in my system32 (or any dir in the path env variable) and replace

```
dir = spawnSync('dir'),
```

By

```
dir = spawnSync('dir.cmd'), //This file is now in a dir in the PATH env var
```

So, i think this is related to a no-auto-resolution of the files with a sh,cmd or something else extention
But this isn't working when I replace the "service" by a "service.sh" anyway (from the first piece of code)

So, maybe someone already did this before and can help me a bit ?

Thanks,
And have a nice day !

Comment: Of course, i can write a service.sh file in a dir in the path env var, wich can take args and forward all this to the real service script, but... i want a cleaner thing

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues, first, when using `spawn`, you should pass the arguments withing an array. Second, you're trying to run two processes within one spawn.

Instead, you can break down two processes and use the `stdout` from the first process (`service`), as the `stdin` for the second one (`grep`). I believe this should do it:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const service = spawn('service', ['teamspeak', 'status']);
const grep = spawn('grep', ['active']);

service.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  grep.stdin.write(data);
});

service.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`service stderr: ${data}`);
});

service.on('close', (code) => {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.log(`ps process exited with code ${code}`);
  }
  grep.stdin.end();
});

grep.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

grep.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`grep stderr: ${data}`);
});

grep.on('close', (code) => {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.log(`grep process exited with code ${code}`);
  }
});
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: That worked, many thanks
I didn't knew this trick to redirect stdout like this
You are the guy !
Have a nice day ;)